# How do I cover large gaps of floor from wall with baseboard?

Tags: baseboard, laminate-floor

I just installed laminate floors in my basement.

One wall (drywall) is not perfectly straight, leaving an area of the floor with a space as big as 1 3/4 inches from the wall.

I don't like the idea of rip cutting a laminate floor piece to a thin and long triangle shape to fill the gap.

What's an easy way of covering the gap?

Comment: If it was 3/4" to 1" max, you could get away with base trim and shoe or quarter-round, but not 1-3/4" - that's a huge gap.  Only option there would be to cover it with a couch or TV stand.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way to cover the gap is to use your same flooring material. In this case the laminate flooring would be cut in a strip to fit the gap. Measure the gap width every 16 or 24 inches and transfer that to a flooring piece minus the normal wall gap clearance. Then cut the strip along a line through the measurements points and fit the piece in place.

Any kind of other strange scheme you come up with to avoid making the long strip is going to look terrible.

Comment: I also though of a few additional choice words I could have used in place of "terrible".

Comment: A laminate floor piece with the shape of a right triangle, 1.25 x 16 x 16 inches does not sound fun to cut. Not to mention "clicking" it in place after everything is laid out already. I have a circular saw, a jig saw and a dremel. What would be the best tool?

Comment: @RolloR - What tool did you use to cut the flooring when other runs came up to the wall? Use the same tool. As far as cutting the piece you may be able to clamp it to a piece of plywood set across two saw horses. Another scheme may be to clamp it between two pieces of plywood that have the edges aligned along the cut line. You could then run the saw blade right along the edge of the plywood pieces. If you do this you may want to use double stick tape to keep the piece in place against one of the two pieces of plywood.